# How do you flatten a hash of key,value pairs?

Tags: perl, hash, query-string

I wanted to share with you guys a function I had created to see how I could optimize it, or if there was a better way to do this.

```
  sub flatten{
    my($ref,$delim,$item_delim,$array,$str) = @_;

    die("Required Hash Reference") unless isHash($ref);

    $delim = $delim ? $delim  :'_';

      #dump into array hash vals #simplified
      if(!$item_delim){
        @{$array} = %{$ref};
      }else{
        my($keys,$values);

        $keys = getKeys($ref);
        $values = getValues($ref);

        #item strings
        if($#$keys > 0 && $#$values > 0){
          #fix for issue where value[n] is empty
          @{$array}= map{ (defined $$values[ $_ ]) ? $$keys[ $_ ].$item_delim.$$values[ $_ ] : $$keys[ $_ ].$item_delim } 0 .. int($#$keys);
        }else{
         log "No Values to flatten";
         return '';
        }
      }

    $str = join($delim,@{$array});
    return $str;
  }
```

Are there any optimization points I should be aware of here?

Basically I want to go from

```
$HASH => {

 key1 => 'val1',
 key2 => 'val2',
 key3 => 'val3',

}
```

to `$STRING= key1=val1&key2=val2 ...`

**UPDATED**

a solution without Modules is preferred I really just want to know how to effectively flatten a hash!.

Note that some of the functions here are simply wrapper functions that do what they say. isHash getKeys... pay no attention to those!

Comment: Why areyou using function like `isHash`, `getKeys`, `getValues`? Is this part of a company standard? And can you not use simple arrays and hashes instead of references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without modules:

```
my $hashref = {    
  key1 => 'val1',
  key2 => 'val2',
  key3 => 'val3',  
};

sub encode {
  my $str = shift;
  $str =~ s/([^A-Za-z0-9\.\/\_\-])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg;
  return $str;
}

my $str = join '&' => map { encode($_).'='.encode($hashref->{$_}) } grep { defined $hashref->{$_} } keys %$hashref;
```

result:

```
key2=val2&key1=val1&key3=val3
```

Answer (score 6):

One convenient way is to use [URI](https://metacpan.org/module/URI)'s `query_form` facility.

```
use URI;

my $uri = URI->new("", "http"); # We don't actually care about the path...
$uri->query_form(%params);
my $query_string = $uri->query;
```

Another, more manual way, is to just use [URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/module/URI::Escape), map, and join.

Comment: @nodebunny If you're labouring under strange restrictions, you should mention them in your question. If you are not willing to use the module, go to http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI and look at the source and take what you need.

Comment: @nodebunny it doesn't seem that you know what the word "flatten" means. The way to flatten a hash in perl is `@kv = %hash`.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything in your question which means that your subroutine needs to be any more complex than:

```
sub flatten {
  my ($hash, $delim, $item_delim) = @_;

  $delim //= '&',
  $item_delim //= '=';

  return join $delim, map { "$_$item_delim$hash->{$_}" } keys %$hash;
}
```

**Update:** Getting a few downvotes here. I assume that people object to the fact that I'm not URI-encoding anything. I'll just point out that there's nothing in the original question saying that we're building URIs. If I knew that we were, then I'd certainly use the [appropriate module](https://metacpan.org/module/URI).

This is why I said "I can't see anything in your question...".

Answer (score 0):

```
use URI::Escape;
my $str=join '&',map {uri_escape($_).'='.uri_escape($QUERY_STRING->{$_})} grep {defined $QUERY_STRING->{$_}} keys %$QUERY_STRING;
```

I think this should work!

Comment: It's missing the escaping. If your keys or values contain any of a [pretty long list](https://metacpan.org/module/URI::Escape) of characters, this'll blow up.

Comment: @nodebunny, to do it without modules use a regex to match all the unsafe characters and replace it by the hex number that represent then! like this (or very close to!) s/([^[\w-\.\~]])/sprintf("%02X",ord $1)/eg;